# Copy Pasting Range to new page if it can't fit in current

Tags: excel, vba

```
For i = 1 + num_ranges To n

ws.Range("newRange").Copy


Set nextCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
nextCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll


Next i
```

Currently copy and pasting a range up to N times and it works just fine. What I would like is to only paste it if the entire range can fit in the page. Otherwise, go to the next page and continue pasting.
The way I'm thinking is to only paste if (Last row in page - nextCell) > the amount of rows the range has (6) else set nextCell to first row in next page but can't figure out how to get the last (or first row) of current/next page.

Comment: If `(nextCell + ws.Range("newRange").Rows.Count) > ws.Rows.Count` then move to the next sheet.

Comment: FYI the next sheet after `ws` (assuming there is one) is returned by `ws.Next`

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, when I said page I meant more like 1 page if it were printed (Like what it says on the bottom left, page 1 of 10) , not sure if there's a better way to say it in excel terms.  Page 1 is rows 1-44, 45-90 is page 2, 91-137 is page 3 etc. I don't want the range to be cut and separated onto two pages. I know that it depends on paper size/row size but based purely on what it shows on the page layout is there a way to get the first/last row of a page? Looking for 1, 44, 45, 90, etc in my example.

Comment: My mistake - lots of posts here on fitting data across multiple tabs so I jumped to that...  Can we assume that pasted data doesn't change the line height?  It's more difficult when that might happen - you'd need to paste and then see if the page breaks changed.

Comment: No problem. Page Break was what I was looking for, thanks! Wasn't too sure what they were called so difficult to search. ws.HPageBreaks(1).Location.Row - 1 is how I'm finding the last one, only part I'm stuck on is how to change the 1 to be whatever page I'm currently on

Comment: The pasted data does not change the line height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code I used for testing.  You should be able to adjust for your needs.

```vb
Sub CopyPasteWithPageBreaks()
    
    Dim f As Worksheet, i As Long, rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim pb As Long, newPaste As Range, pgBrk As HPageBreak, nC, nR
    
    Set rngCopy = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I20") 'some data to copy
    nC = rngCopy.Columns.Count
    nR = rngCopy.Rows.Count
    
    Set f = Sheets("Sheet1")
    f.Cells.Clear
    DoEvents
    
    Set rngPaste = f.Range("A1")
    
    For i = 1 To 10
        
        pb = f.HPageBreaks.Count 'current # of page breaks

        'set up the copy range so it's clear which iteration the pasted content was from
        rngCopy.Value = i   
        rngCopy.Font.Color = IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, vbRed, vbBlue)
        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste
        DoEvents
        
        If f.HPageBreaks.Count > pb Then 'added a page break by pasting?
            
            If i = 1 Then
                'If the first paste creates a new page break then
                '   the copied range will not fit on a page....
                MsgBox "Range is too large for 1 page!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            Set pgBrk = f.HPageBreaks(f.HPageBreaks.Count)
            Debug.Print "new pagebreak " & pgBrk.Location.Address
            
            Set newPaste = f.Cells(pgBrk.Location.Row, "A")
            rngPaste.Resize(nC, nR).Clear 'clear last paste
            rngCopy.Copy newPaste         're-copy to top of next page
            
            Set rngPaste = newPaste.Offset(nR)
        Else
            Set rngPaste = rngPaste.Offset(nR)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```